# how I can retrieve json in vuejs

Tags: laravel-4, vue.js

How can I retrieve json in Vuejs in `vue.js` in laravel 4?
I tried following  but it didn't work:

```js
  
     new Vue({ 
        el: '#guestbook',
        data: {
            comments: [],
            text: '',
            author: ''
        },
        ready: function() {
            this.getMessages();
        },
        methods: {
            getMessages: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    context: this,
                    url: "/cms/Getweb_manager",
                    success: function (result) {
                        this.$set("comments", result) 
                    }
                })
            }
          
        }
    })
```

Comment: you should take a look at [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) instead of using ajax (well, vue resource use ajax in a _vue way_).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the response? Just use a `console.log(result)`.
About your doubt, you probably have to do `this.$set('comments', result.data');`.

Don't forget the semicolon!

Comment: hy Mateus Guimarães do you have using vue.js in laravel 4

Comment: The framework don't really matters. What matters is getting the right jSON response. By the way, why haven't you updated to L5?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the vue-resource package 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource

It should work like this

```
methods: {
  getMessages: function() {
    this.$http({
      url: '/cms/Getweb_manager', 
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
      // success callback
      this.$set('comments', response.result);
    }, function (response) {
      // error callback
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i have number of http requests in a single page, is there any alternate to make it global http ? if you have any working example for same please post it here